# Atalho para formatar código JSP não funciona no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Analisei vários posts, mas não consigo formatar códigos em páginas JSP com o atalho do Eclipse, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, assim não conseguindo indentar o código. Em códigos Javascript e Java funciona, mas não em JSP.

Preciso muito reconfigurar este atalho no Eclipse (luna), pois estou trabalhando com Bootstrap, pegando código da documentação, e é muito ruim sem indentar.

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

PS: no fim da JSP tenho uma tag `<script>` com um código Javascript, lá formata e comenta. Que estranho, só em TAG HTML NÃO.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, faz um tempo q não utilizo o eclipse, mas acredito q é com esse comando aqui:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: Cara, assim eu vi num post também, legal, mas formata o código todo. Com o ctrl+shift+f eu escolho somente o trecho que preciso.